# How do I solve a folder capitalization conflict with Git on Windows?

Tags: git

I'm doing a `git rebase`, and I'm stuck because in one commit I have a folder named `Proto`, but in the other commit I have a folder named `proto`. It was an honest mistake and should have been `Proto` in both cases. The best I can figure out here is to try deleting the folder from both commits and then trying the rebase again, but there has to be a better way.

In the past, when I've run into capitalization problems with a file, I've used git mv, but with the folder it won't let me run git mv, and I don't know why.

What's the correct way to fix a folder capitalization problem  in git on Windows?

Answer (score 18):

We encountered a similar issue in our git repository on Windows when a large number of files were moved around to different directories.

I fixed our issue the first time manually by cloning the repository to a Linux VM and running a bash script with `git mv` commands to fix the file path case issue. This was a painful process so I decided to develop a utility that automates the process.

[Git Unite](https://github.com/tawman/git-unite) is a .NET console application I wrote using the [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) library. The program identifies all git index entries with file path case different from what the Windows file system reports.

I wrote a blog posting detailing the tool, usage, and history behind it at [Git Unite - Fix Case Sensitive File Paths on Windows](http://www.woodcp.com/2013/01/git-unite-fix-case-sensitive-file-paths-on-windows/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this tool! It's saved us a couple of hours of manually fixing our messy repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That was very helpful for us here! It is effective and simple to use

Answer (score 1):

Smuggling folder renames into Git history is difficult, because folders are not tracked -- only files in the folders. Assuming that you want to rename `oldFolder` to `oldfolder` you could try the following:

1. Rebase interactively from the point where you first created a file in `oldFolder`. Edit every commit that adds files to this folder. When interactive rebase stops, create `newFolder` and execute `git mv oldFolder/* newFolder/`. Do the latter for each stop of the interactive rebase.
2. Obviously, you cannot have `oldFolder` and `newFolder` be two differently capitalized versions of the same word in Windows. Hence, repeat step 1 to rename `newFolder` to `oldfolder`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out I had to go back and delete the folder from one branch, perform the rebase, then manually add the files back in post rebase.

Answer (score 0):

[`git config --global core.ignorecase true`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) should solve your problem on Windows.

Comment: Will this allow rewriting the history so that capitalization is corrected?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]
I suspect you need to "git mv" each file in the folder to a temp name like 'ProtoX', then "git mv" the temp-named files to 'Proto', as Git does not track folders by themselves -- only the files in the folders.

The double "git mv" works around Windows case-insensitive filesystems. (You should be able to move directly from 'proto' to 'Proto' on case-sensitive filesystems, like Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `git mv` on each file, or an external tool, you can trick git into staging the rename operation by:

1. Rename the folder to have a distinctly new name, like "Proto_X"
2. Stage the *parent* folder, `git add .`
3. Rename the folder to the desired name, including case, like "Proto"
4. Stage the *parent* folder again, `git add .`

This works because the staging operation is where case differences are determined.