# IntelliJ Git Integration plugin -> "New Branch" puts capital F in "feature/abc"

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, plugins, branching-and-merging

Using IntlliJ 15.0.6 and Git Integration plugin.

When I use the GUI button at the bottom right of the screen (click on `Git: develop`) to display `Git Branches` popoup and choose `+ New Branch`

Enter branch name: `feature/abc`

Yet branch is created with capital F: `Feature/abc`

Is this a bug (and if so where... intellij, plugin, or git) ?

Can I fix it (other than using command line every time I create a branch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a git thing combined with the whether or not the filesystem that you are using is case sensitive or not. Related to [Why is git capitalizing my branch name prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371866/why-is-git-capitalizing-my-branch-name-prefix)

Take a look at the below, done on OSX using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

1. First we create a couple of branches, `feature/abc`, `feature/xyz`. No problems here, branches are created with the expected case:

[image]

2. Next we create a branch called `Feature/pqr`, now this branch will be created with a lower case `feature` since a `feature*` branch already exists on the file system :

[image]

3. Finally, create a new branch `SomeOtherFeature/blah` and this will be created with the correct case since it has never been created before on the filesystem:

[image]

If you were to now create a `someotherfeature/blah2` then this would retain the case of the first branch (i.e. will get created as `SomeOtherFeature/blah2`.