# How do I undo my git tags becoming captalized?

Tags: git

For some reason, all of my git tags in my repository have been capitalized.

Before, there were like `abc-123` when running `git tag --list`. Now all of the tags are appearing like `Abc-123` with the first letter capitalized. This is preventing me from pushing any of my tags to remote. How do I make them go back to their original capitalization?

Git version:

```
> git version
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371866/why-is-git-capitalizing-my-branch-name-prefix

Comment: Hi, could you provide more information? Tags changing its name sounds to me to file system problems. Your .git directory was somehow modified or got corrupt? They wont change names just like that, some action was made ;)

Comment: I noticed that the git directory for the repository became `.git\refs\tags\Feature`. I now changed it to `.git\refs\tags\feature` and now the problem is fixed. I don't know how it became capitalized in the first place.