# How to change the capital letter of the name of a new branch via intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Creating a new branch via intellij idea, for example

```
feature/...
```

The IDE renames it to

```
Feature/...
```

I try to manually change the uppercase letter to a lowercase one, but it still renames it to the uppercase one. IDE version 2021.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE relies on command-line Git and you may check whether the same behavior takes place when you run `git checkout -b feature/...`

But it seems that you've already had branches with the prefix `Feature` and it seems that you are running on case insensitive OS therefore Git see no difference between `Feature` and `feature`

Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15372154/12360005

Comment: the branches with the Feature prefix were indeed there. Windows OS

Comment: Thank you renamed the directory in git itself and now I have a lowercase letter