# How to make the branch folder be lowercase in vscode source control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, source-control-explorer

[image][image]

I am using the Git source control in the VS Code. recently I found that if I create the branch like this, **topic**/CIE/LRAT-333, then I push that in to remote repo, finally in the VS code, choose source control on the left navigation, then click remote, I found that the branch folder became capital, **TOPIC**/CIE/LRAT-333. but when I check it in the azure repos, it is still "topic" lowercase.

I only this the capital topic here. TOPIC  from the element

others are lowercase,  topic/CIE/LRAT-333
[image: this is the screenshot from element]

I found it's in the remote session.
[image: it's in remote session.]
here I attached another screenshot.
[image]

so I don't know why it shows capital letter in the source control. it kind of bring us the confusion. could you please help me out?

```
Version: 1.76.2
Commit: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
Date: 2023-03-14T17:55:54.936Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.14393
Sandboxed: No
```

if it's lowercase, then it should be lowercase in the remote

Comment: yes, I am using the gitlens., I already attached the screenshot

Comment: I can't see the picture in the description, but a link

Comment: does this happen for all your branches? If not, show all your branch names so we can see what the difference between them is.

Comment: yes, for all branches.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: I attached one screenshot in the problem description

Comment: it would be nice to have a screenshot that shows what element in the rendered page the element in the element inspector is associated with.

Comment: I found that it's in remote session.

Comment: It's really hard to correlate what you're showing in the devtools screenshots to the actual VS Code workbench (window). I asked you to show a screenshot that also shows the workbench and highlights what the element corresponds to.

Comment: I attached another one sceenshot, could you please help check

Comment: okay why does it now show "TOPIC" in remotes instead of "TOPIC/CIE/LRAT-333" like it showed in your earlier screenshot?

Comment: I created another topic so it showed in seperated layers. topic/CIE/LRAT-333 and topic/CID/LRAT-334,  like
  
TOPIC
  ---CIE
     ----LRAT-333
  ---CID
     ----LRAT-334

Comment: if only one branch it showed "TOPIC/CIE/LRAT-333", but if more than one branch, it shows different lines, first line is TOPIC, second line the sub folders, and then in seperated sub folders, and third line shows the branch name

Answer (score 0):

Branches are by default organized as files and directories. Some file systems and operating systems are case-insensitive, such as Windows.

Check in your `.git/refs/heads` directory, if you find a `TOPIC` or `topic` directory (there can only be one).

To fix, you need to manually rename the directory (not really recommended), or rename *all* affected branches to something else, then after there are no more references to topic/TOPIC, rename them back.

Also make sure to update your remote accordingly (Linux generally is case-sensitive and `topic/abc` and `TOPIC/abc` are two completely distinct branches)

Comment: How should I manually rename the directory?

Comment: @user17900382 just like any other directory that you would rename. F2 in Windows Explorer, `ren` or `rename` in the command prompt. Copy, paste, then delete the old one. Take your pick

Comment: if this is your answer, why not dup vote to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15371866/11107541 ?

Comment: @starball I wasn't aware of the dupe. Thanks for linking, I have closed the question now and linked the dupe